# How to modify ScrollView scroll sensitivity?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, scrollview

I have a horizontal ScrollView with paging enabled and each page is vertical FlatList.

Often, when users try to scroll down on FlatList, horizontal scroll happens and they end up on next ScrollView page.

Is there a way to configure ScrollView sensitivity so it triggers only when horizontal drag is larger, if that makes sense?

I've already looked into documentation, but haven't found anything.

```
<ScrollView
    ref={swiperRef}
    horizontal={true}
    decelerationRate={'normal'}
    snapToInterval={screenWidth} 
    snapToAlignment={'center'}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    disableIntervalMomentum={true}
    >
    {categories.map((category, index) => {
        return (
            <View key={category?.code}>
               <FlatList
                  data={categories[index]}
                  renderItem={renderBox}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                  contentContainerStyle={styles.categoryNewsContainer}
                  onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
                    loadMore()
                  }}
                  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                  onRefresh={() => refresh()}
                  refreshing={isRefreshing}
                />
            </View>
                )
    })}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just user [decelerationRate](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#decelerationrate) for speed either "fast"/"normal" or just any float

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with the vertical scrolling being too sensitive. This was my solution in native Android, so maybe it could help:

https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/ui/detail/NestedScrollingParentScrollView.kt